# how to set dynamic value to hidden field on document.ready function

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert($("#hdnDivValue").val());
        var VisibleDiv = $("#hdnDivValue");
        var Task = $("#DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv");
        var TaskReport = $("#DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv");
        var LeaveReport = $("#DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv");

        var btnLeaveMang1 = $("#btnLeaveMang");
        var btnMy_Task1 = $("#btnMy_Task");
        var btn_TaskReport1 = $("#btn_TaskReport");
        //var btnlLeaveSave1 = $("$btnlLeaveSave");

//        btnlLeaveSave1.click(function () {
//            $("#hdnDivValue").val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");
//            alert('working');
//        });

        btn_TaskReport1.click(function () {

            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d - L_Mytaskdiv";
            TaskReport.show();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.hide();

        });

        btnMy_Task1.click(function () {

            // VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv";
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.show();
            LeaveReport.hide();
        });

        btnLeaveMang1.click(function () {

            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.show();
            $("#hdnDivValue").val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");
            alert($("#hdnDivValue").val());
            //VisibleDiv.val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");

        });



        if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv") {

            TaskReport.show();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.hide();
            // VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d - L_Comptaskdiv";
        }

        else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv") {
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.show();
            LeaveReport.hide();
            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv";

        }
        else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv") {

            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.show();
            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";

        }



    });
</script>
```

this is my jquery code :

the logic behind i used through this code is :
    i have three div respectively 
         div1
         div2
         div3
     and i have one hidden field....

intially i set the hidden field value to div3 so div3 is displayed according to the code...

```
     else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv") {

            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.show();
            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";

        }
```

----- and i have three button also....when i click on first button div1 is displayed and              set the hiddenfield value to div1 id ......my problem is when pageload occurs the hidden field value , set to intial value i.e div3 value instead of div1 i.e  bind respective last button click div id value any body have any idea...to solve this issue....in asp.net we have view state is it any function in javascript to get last valued stored

Comment: Can you please post html also?

Comment: <div id="DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv" class="DF_d-L_Mytask">
                <div class="FullMargins">
                <div> 
                  
                                        
                                       
                                
                            
        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: Are you saying that when you reload the page your default values have reset back to div3 and this is not the desired result? If so that is because you need to post your new value back to the server script so that it reissues this back to your output html.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/m9L5h/1/) @Muhammad Omair

Comment: @DavidHirst if we post our new value to server script ok fine we we can get it back but before that ..document.ready function is occured..

Comment: @davidhirst so again div3 is displayed...my issues is when i work on current div sever control the div hide and intial div is displayed...this is my issue....on my current div i have gridview to display it i have to button click event i.e server side button click event when it happened my current div hide and intailly setted div displaying so cannot stable on my current div...

Comment: Yes but that sounds like you are reloading the page. If you are reloading the page, this clears the dom and then reloads from your defaults, which will be div3. What you need to do is post back the new setting, via ajax so that when you reload the page, you can pass the new default value back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First up all i thanks to @David Hirst,@Muhammad Omair 

This is my jquery code : 

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        //alert($("#hdnDivValue").val());
        var VisibleDiv = $("#hdnDivValue");
        var Task = $("#DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv");
        var TaskReport = $("#DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv");
        var LeaveReport = $("#DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv");

        var btnLeaveMang1 = $("#btnLeaveMang");
        var btnMy_Task1 = $("#btnMy_Task");
        var btn_TaskReport1 = $("#btn_TaskReport");
        //var btnlLeaveSave1 = $("$btnlLeaveSave");

//        btnlLeaveSave1.click(function () {
//            $("#hdnDivValue").val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");
//            alert('working');
//        });

        btn_TaskReport1.click(function () {

            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d - L_Mytaskdiv";
            TaskReport.show();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.hide();

        });

        btnMy_Task1.click(function () {

            // VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv";
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.show();
            LeaveReport.hide();
        });

        btnLeaveMang1.click(function () {

            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.show();
            $("#hdnDivValue").val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");
            //alert($("#hdnDivValue").val());
            //VisibleDiv.val("DF_d - L_LeaveReqdiv");

        });



        if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv") {

            TaskReport.show();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.hide();
            // VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d - L_Comptaskdiv";
        }

        else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv") {
            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.show();
            LeaveReport.hide();
            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv";

        }
        else if (VisibleDiv.val() == "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv") {

            TaskReport.hide();
            Task.hide();
            LeaveReport.show();
            //VisibleDiv.val() = "DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv";

        }



    });
</script>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                hdnDivValue.Value = "DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv";
            }
        }

//hidden field set to default div namely "DF_d_Comptaskdiv" 
//so intially "DF_d_Comptaskdiv" div is displayed
```

protected void btnTaskView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        General.officeStaff ofcobj = new officeStaff();
        ofcobj.BindTaskGrid(grdTask);
        hdnDivValue.Value = "DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv";
    }
```

`enter code here`//set hiddenfield value to current div where server ctrl reside....so asp.net maintain the viewstate of hiddenfield value to current div....like that every div server ctrl value is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER IT IS A SUGGESTION**

I am sorry I do not understand what it is your trying to accomplish but may I suggest a slight clean up of your current jQuery to something like this which is a lot more readable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var Task = $("#DF_d-L_Mytaskdiv");
var TaskReport = $("#DF_d-L_Comptaskdiv");
var LeaveReport = $("#DF_d-L_LeaveReqdiv");    

$("#btn_TaskReport").on('click', function() {
    showTaskReport();
}

$("#btnMy_Task").on('click', function() {
    showTask();
}

$("#btnLeaveMang").on('click', function() {
    showLeaveReport();
}

function showTaskReport() {
    TaskReport.show();
    Task.hide();
    LeaveReport.hide();
}

function showTask() {
    TaskReport.hide();
    Task.show();
    LeaveReport.hide();    
}

function showLeaveReport() {
    TaskReport.hide();
    Task.hide();
    LeaveReport.show();        
}
});
```

Comment: my issue i have 3 div and three html button... when div1 is displayed intially and all others are hide at first time when in click button2 div2 displayed and div2 have serer ctrl button when i click on it current div i.e div2 is hiding and intial div i.e div1 is display ....i am searching the solution to be in div2 when server button click also...